# How do I speed up my Amicable number algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

It take pretty long time to complete the limit(n) of 100,000.

I suspect that the problem is with the *CalculateAmicable()* where the number get bigger and it take more time to calculate. What can I change to make it speed up faster than this?

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        CheckAmicable (1, 100000);

    }

    public static int CheckAmicable(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

            int main = CalculateAmicable (i); //220
            int temp = CalculateAmicable (main); //284
            int compare = CalculateAmicable (temp); //220
            if (compare == main) {
                if (main != temp && temp == i) {
                    Console.WriteLine (main + " = " + temp + " = " + compare + " i: " + i);
                    i = compare + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static int CalculateAmicable(int number)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
            if (number%i == 0){
                total += i;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Note: English is not my first language!

Comment: In `CalculateAmicable` you can loop from 1 to the square root of `number` and add every time 2 to the total.

Comment: @xzoert I was thinking on the same lines as you but don't think it works. To verify, try plugging the number 9 into the existing method. I think instead if you loop from 1 to half the value of number and increment total by 1 this should work.

Comment: It does work. You add `total += i + number / i` each time. You are summing the divisors, not getting the number of them. You need a check to avoid adding the `number` itself though (with 1).

Comment: Good catch. I'm reading this on a 7" tablet and read total += i as total += 1!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `CalculateAmicable` is *inefficient* - `O(N)` complexity - and so you have fo `N` tests `1e5 * 1e5 == 1e10` - *ten billions* operations which is slow.
The scheme which reduces complexity to `O(log(N))` is

```
  int n = 100000;

  //TODO: implement IList<int> GetPrimesUpTo(int) yourself
  var primes = GetPrimesUpTo((int)(Math.Sqrt(n + 1) + 1));

  // Key - number itself, Value - divisors' sum 
  var direct = Enumerable
    .Range(1, n)
    .AsParallel()
    .ToDictionary(index => index, 
                  index => GetDivisorsSum(index, primes) - index);

  var result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, n)
    .Where(x => x < direct[x] && 
                direct.ContainsKey((int) direct[x]) &&
                direct[(int) direct[x]] == x)
    .Select(x => $"{x,5}, {direct[x],5}");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

The outcome is within a second (Core i7 3.2Ghz .Net 4.6 IA-64):

```
  220,   284
 1184,  1210
 2620,  2924
 5020,  5564
 6232,  6368
10744, 10856
12285, 14595
17296, 18416
63020, 76084
66928, 66992
67095, 71145
69615, 87633
79750, 88730
```

Details `GetDivisorsSum`:

```
private static long GetDivisorsSum(long value, IList<int> primes) {
  HashSet<long> hs = new HashSet<long>();

  IList<long> divisors = GetPrimeDivisors(value, primes);

  ulong n = (ulong) 1;
  n = n << divisors.Count;

  long result = 1;

  for (ulong i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    ulong v = i;
    long p = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < divisors.Count; ++j) {
      if ((v % 2) != 0)
        p *= divisors[j];

      v = v / 2;
    }

    if (hs.Contains(p))
      continue;

    result += p;

    hs.Add(p);
  }

  return result;
}
```

And `GetPrimeDivisors`:

```
private static IList<long> GetPrimeDivisors(long value, IList<int> primes) {
  List<long> results = new List<long>();

  int v = 0;
  long threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < primes.Count; ++i) {
    v = primes[i];

    if (v > threshould)
      break;

    if ((value % v) != 0)
      continue;

    while ((value % v) == 0) {
      value = value / v;

      results.Add(v);
    }

    threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);
  }

  if (value > 1)
    results.Add(value);

  return results;
}
```