# Pairs of amicable numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I have a task to find pairs of amicable numbers and I've already solved it. My solution is not efficient, so please help me to make my algorithm faster.

Amicable numbers are two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. The smallest pair of amicable numbers is (220, 284). They are amicable because the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110, of which the sum is 284; and the proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142, of which the sum is 220.

Task: two `long` numbers and find the first amicable numbers between them. Let s(n) be the sum of the proper divisors of n:

For example:

```
s(10) = 1 + 2 + 5 = 8
s(11) = 1
s(12) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16
```

If `s(firstlong) == s(secondLong)` they are amicable numbers

My code:

```
public static IEnumerable<long> Ranger(long length) {
  for (long i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    yield return i;
  }
}

public static IEnumerable<long> GetDivisors(long num) {
  return from a in Ranger(num/2)
    where num % a == 0
    select a;
}

public static string FindAmicable(long start, long limit) {
  long numberN = 0;
  long numberM = 0;

  for (long n = start; n <= limit; n++) {
    long sumN = GetDivisors(n).Sum();      
    long m = sumN;

    long sumM = GetDivisors(m).Sum();

    if (n == sumM ) {
      numberN = n;      
      numberM = m;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $"First amicable numbers: {numberN} and {numberM}";
}
```

Comment: the first help, not a lot , i can say you is that your range function, could start at 2 because all numbers are divisible for 1 then you don't have to check and sum this one. I will check the options because i think that the key is to check the divisors of the number since one moment, then you know if it will be amigable or break to the next.

Comment: Not much of help, but according to wikipedia there exists no odd-even pair of amicable number(It may exist but still not found) so if n is odd/even and sumN=even/odd you can reject. Moreover [Vaxasoftware](http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/numamigos_eng.pdf) has a huge list of maicable numbers, which may be helpful to you.

Comment: see if you can get anything out of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653159/how-do-i-speed-up-my-amicable-number-algorithm

Comment: You could also memoize the sums for a given n, although that would only help in the case where multiple ns generate the same m, which I don't know if that would happen in practice. I'm also not clear if m needs to be between start and limit too, which you don't check.

Comment: @Rup m can be greater than limit

Comment: @MichaelRandall There is also not an effective solution

Comment: A large list of amicable numbers: https://sech.me/ap/. It has a paper on methods to find these: https://sech.me/ap/articles.html

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't write C#, so rather than stumble through some incoherent C# spaghetti, I'll describe an improvement in C#-madeup-psuedo-code.

The problem seems to be in your `GetDivisors` function. This is linear `O(n)` time with respect to each divisor `n`, when it could be `O(sqrt(n))`. The trick is to only divide up to the square root, and infer the rest of the factors from that.

```
GetDivisors(num) {
    // same as before, but up to sqrt(num), plus a bit for floating point error
    yield return a     in Ranger((long)sqrt(num + 0.5)) where num % a == 0

    if ((long)sqrt(num + 0.5) ** 2 == num) { // perfect square, exists
        num -= 1 // don't count it twice
    }

    // repeat, but return the "other half"-  num / a  instead of  a
    yield return num/a in Ranger((long)sqrt(num + 0.5)) where num % a == 0
}
```

This will reduce your complexity of that portion from `O(n)` to `O(sqrt(n))`, which should provide a noticeable speedup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple formula giving the sum of divisors of a number knowing its prime decomposition:

```
 let x = p1^a1 * ... * pn^an, where pi is a prime for all i
 sum of divisors = (1+p1+...+p1^a1) * ... (1+pn+...+pn^an)
                 = (1-p1^(a1+1))/(1-p1) * ... ((1-pn^(an+1))/(1-pn)
```

In order to do a prime decomposition you must compute all prime numbers up to the square root of the maximal value in your search range. This is easily done using the sieve of Erathostenes.